# Android Convert longitude to GPS tag of ExifInterface

Tags: android, exif, geotagging

i want to convert from Latitude, Longitude to GPS tag of ExifInterface

Ex: 10.34534564 to format like that http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#TAG_GPS_LATITUDE "114/1,3/1,207045/4096"

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GPS coordinates comes in three basic forms. The example you have chosen `10.34534564` is called DMS format. DMS stads for Degree Minutes Seconds. When we use `location.getLatitude();` we will get an output like your example (10.34534564). But when we want to use that value with `ExifInterface` we have to convert that value in to DMS format. Study this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion) to know about the conversion from Decimal Degree to DMS.

Comment: Note that the java example given in the link will result in significant rounding of the seconds.  Multiply both num and denom by 1000 to maintain accuracy.